# Get pixel color from screen in C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, beginner, linux, c++17, x11

For a long period of time I worked on this code, mostly trying to understand it. That is the main reason for needed review. Second reason is simply that I would like to optimize it in any way you can find.

Side note: **I have shortened the code as humanly possible**.

Compilation of the below code:

```sh
g++-8 -O2 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors getPixelColor.cpp -o getPixelColor $(pkg-config --cflags --libs x11)
```

---

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <cmath> // round()

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/59663458/1997354
inline __attribute__((always_inline)) \
unsigned long MyXGetPixel(XImage * ximage, const int & x, const int & y)
{
    return (*ximage->f.get_pixel)(ximage, x, y);
}

void MyGetPixelColor(Display * my_display, const int & x_coord, const int & y_coord, XColor * pixel_color)
{
    XImage * screen_image = XGetImage(
        my_display,
        XRootWindow(my_display, XDefaultScreen(my_display)),
        x_coord, y_coord,
        1, 1,
        AllPlanes,
        XYPixmap
    );
    pixel_color->pixel = MyXGetPixel(screen_image, 0, 0);
    XFree(screen_image);
    XQueryColor(my_display, XDefaultColormap(my_display, XDefaultScreen(my_display)), pixel_color);
}

// usage
int main()
{

Display * my_display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
XColor screen_pixel_color;
// in this example let's take [0,0] coordinates
MyGetPixelColor(my_display, 0, 0, & screen_pixel_color);
XCloseDisplay(my_display);

unsigned short raw_r_value = screen_pixel_color.red;
unsigned short raw_g_value = screen_pixel_color.green;
unsigned short raw_b_value = screen_pixel_color.blue;

std::cout
    << "R = " << round(raw_r_value / 256.0) << std::endl
    << "G = " << round(raw_g_value / 256.0) << std::endl
    << "B = " << round(raw_b_value / 256.0) << std::endl;

}
```

---

### Unshortened || full code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <cmath> // round()
//#include <cstring>
//#include <cstdlib>
//#include <gdk/gdk.h>
//#include <gtk/gtk.h>
//#include <X11/Xutil.h>
//#include </usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>
//#include <ncurses.h>

class BasicCoordinates
{
private:
    long long X;
    long long Y;

public:
    BasicCoordinates(const long long & _X, const long long & _Y)
    {
        X = _X;
        Y = _Y;
    }
    long long getX()
    {
        return X;
    }
    long long getY()
    {
        return Y;
    }

};

bool StringContainsInteger(const std::string & str)
// true : if the string contains an integer number (possibly starting with a sign)
// false: if the string contains some other character(s)
{
    std::string::size_type str_len = str.length();
    if (str_len == 0) return false;

    bool sign_present = (str[0] == '-' || str[0] == '+');
    if (str_len == 1 && sign_present) return false;

    for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < str_len; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0 && sign_present) continue;
        if (! std::isdigit((unsigned char) str[i])) return false;
    }

    return true;
}


// https://stackoverflow.com/a/59663458/1997354
inline __attribute__((always_inline)) \
unsigned long MyXGetPixel(XImage * ximage, const int & x, const int & y)
{
    return (*ximage->f.get_pixel)(ximage, x, y);
}

void MyGetPixelColor(Display * my_display, const int & x_coord, const int & y_coord, XColor * pixel_color)
{
    XImage * screen_image = XGetImage(
        my_display,
        XRootWindow(my_display, XDefaultScreen(my_display)),
        x_coord, y_coord,
        1, 1,
        AllPlanes,
        XYPixmap
    );
    pixel_color->pixel = MyXGetPixel(screen_image, 0, 0);
    XFree(screen_image);
    XQueryColor(my_display, XDefaultColormap(my_display, XDefaultScreen(my_display)), pixel_color);
}




int main(const int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    const int given_arguments_count = argc - 1;
    if (given_arguments_count != 2)
    {
        std::cerr
            << "Fatal error occurred while checking\n"
            << "the number of given arguments\n"
            << "--------------------------------------\n"
            << "In the function : " << __func__ << std::endl
            << "At the command  : " << "given_arguments_count\n"
            << "Given arguments : " << given_arguments_count << std::endl
            << "Error message   : " << "This program is expecting exactly 2 arguments\n"
            << "                  being the X Y coordinates of a pixel on the screen\n";
        return 1;
    }

    const std::string cli_argument_1 = argv[1];
    if (! StringContainsInteger(cli_argument_1))
    {
        std::cerr
            << "Fatal error occurred while checking\n"
            << "if the first argument contains a number\n"
            << "----------------------------------------\n"
            << "In the function : " << __func__ << std::endl
            << "At the command  : " << "StringContainsInteger\n"
            << "Input string    : " << cli_argument_1 << std::endl
            << "Error message   : " << "The first argument is not an integer number\n";
        return 1;
    }

    const std::string cli_argument_2 = argv[2];
    if (! StringContainsInteger(cli_argument_2))
    {
        std::cerr
            << "Fatal error occurred while checking\n"
            << "if the second argument contains a number\n"
            << "----------------------------------------\n"
            << "In the function : " << __func__ << std::endl
            << "At the command  : " << "StringContainsInteger\n"
            << "Input string    : " << cli_argument_2 << std::endl
            << "Error message   : " << "The second argument is not an integer number\n";
        return 1;
    }

    long long x_coord;
    try
    {
        x_coord = std::stoll(cli_argument_1);
    }
    catch (const std::exception & input_exception)
    {
        std::cerr
            << "Fatal error occurred while converting\n"
            << "the first argument to an integer variable\n"
            << "-------------------------------------\n"
            << "In the function : " << __func__ << std::endl
            << "At the command  : " << input_exception.what() << std::endl
            << "Input string    : " << cli_argument_1 << std::endl
            << "Error message   : " << "The first number argument is too big an integer\n";
        return 1;
    }

    long long y_coord;
    try
    {
        y_coord = std::stoll(cli_argument_2);
    }
    catch (const std::exception & input_exception)
    {
        std::cerr
            << "Fatal error occurred while converting\n"
            << "the second argument to an integer variable\n"
            << "--------------------------------------\n"
            << "In the function : " << __func__ << std::endl
            << "At the command  : " << input_exception.what() << std::endl
            << "Input string    : " << cli_argument_2 << std::endl
            << "Error message   : " << "The second number argument is too big an integer\n";
        return 1;
    }


    BasicCoordinates * pixel_coords = new BasicCoordinates(x_coord, y_coord);
    std::cout << "X = " << pixel_coords->getX() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Y = " << pixel_coords->getY() << std::endl << std::endl;









        Display * my_display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
        Screen * my_screen = XDefaultScreenOfDisplay(my_display);

        const int screen_width = my_screen->width;
        const int screen_height = my_screen->height;

        if (x_coord >= screen_width)
        {
            std::cerr
                << "X coord bigger than the screen with\n"; // TEMP

            return 1;
        }

        if (y_coord >= screen_height)
        {
            std::cerr
                << "Y coord bigger than the screen height\n"; // TEMP

            return 1;
        }



        XWindowAttributes root_window_attributes;
        XGetWindowAttributes(my_display, DefaultRootWindow(my_display), & root_window_attributes);


        XColor screen_pixel_color;


        MyGetPixelColor(my_display, x_coord, y_coord, & screen_pixel_color);

        XCloseDisplay(my_display);



        unsigned short raw_r_value = screen_pixel_color.red;
        unsigned short raw_g_value = screen_pixel_color.green;
        unsigned short raw_b_value = screen_pixel_color.blue;
/*
        std::cout
            << "Raw Values" << std::endl
            << "R = " << raw_r_value << std::endl
            << "G = " << raw_g_value << std::endl
            << "B = " << raw_b_value << std::endl;

        std::cout << std::endl;
*/
        std::cout
//            << "Normalized" << std::endl
            << "R = " << round(raw_r_value / 256.0) << std::endl
            << "G = " << round(raw_g_value / 256.0) << std::endl
            << "B = " << round(raw_b_value / 256.0) << std::endl;



        return 0;

}
```

Comment: Have you written this code yourself? There are indications in your question that you dont understand the code, even just to a degree. This would be off topic on this site.

Comment: @slepic I just partially copied and modified the MyGetPixelColor function.

Comment: For Code Review, you're not supposed to shorten your code. You're supposed to keep it understandable and readable.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Full code added..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class is much more complicated than it needs to be:

> ```
> class BasicCoordinates
> {
> private:
>     long long X;
>     long long Y;
>
> public:
>     BasicCoordinates(const long long & _X, const long long & _Y)
>     {
>         X = _X;
>         Y = _Y;
>     }
>     long long getX()
>     {
>         return X;
>     }
>     long long getY()
>     {
>         return Y;
>     }
>
> };
> ```

A simple aggregate does the job and is more intuitive:

```
struct Coordinates {
    long long x;
    long long y;
};
```

---

This function is also quite convoluted:

> ```
> bool StringContainsInteger(const std::string & str)
> // true : if the string contains an integer number (possibly starting with a sign)
> // false: if the string contains some other character(s)
> {
>     std::string::size_type str_len = str.length();
>     if (str_len == 0) return false;
>
>     bool sign_present = (str[0] == '-' || str[0] == '+');
>     if (str_len == 1 && sign_present) return false;
>
>     for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < str_len; i++)
>     {
>         if (i == 0 && sign_present) continue;
>         if (! std::isdigit((unsigned char) str[i])) return false;
>     }
>
>     return true;
> }
> ```

which is basically just:

```
bool StringContainsInteger(std::string_view str)
{
    // C++20: str.starts_with('+') || str.starts_with('-')
    if (!str.empty() && (str[0] == '+' || str[0] == '-')) {
        str.remove_prefix(1);
    }
    return std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(),
                       [](unsigned char c) { return std::isdigit(c); });
}
```

(note that `std::string_view` is preferable to `const std::string&` if all you want is read the characters in the string).

Comment: I think StringContainsInteger is redundant anyway, one can use the second argument to [`std::stoll()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to check whether all characters in the string have been processed, and only accept the result if that is the case.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Yes. It's better to use that directly since OP is calling `stoll` immediately after validating the string.

Answer (score 1):

## Use `XGetPixel()` instead of writing your own function

You should use the API provided to you by X libraries whenever possible. The implementation details might change over time, so your own copy of `XGetPixel()` might no longer be correct in the future. Granted, this is very unlikely in the case of Xlib, but it is good practice in general.

## Don't pass by const reference unnecessarily

Don't pass small variables by const reference. You typically only do this for non-trivial types where the cost of passing by value is larger than passing by reference, for example `std::string`, `std::vector` and so on. You should never need a const reference for something like an `int`, `float` and so on. So:

```
void MyGetPixelColor(Display *my_display, int x_coord, int y_coord, XColor *pixel_color)
{ ... }
```

## Return by value when appropriate

Functions that return some value should preferably `return` that value, instead of taking a pointer that will be written to. So I would rewrite your code to:

```
Xcolor MyGetPixelColor(Display *my_display, int x_coord, int y_coord)
{
    Xcolor pixel_color;
    XImage *screen_image = ...;
    pixel_color->pixel = XGetPixel(screen_image, 0, 0);
    XFree(screen_image);
    XQueryColor(my_display, XDefaultColormap(my_display, XDefaultScreen(my_display)), pixel_color);

    return pixel_color;
}
```

This doesn't cause extra copies of `Xcolor` to be made, since C++ compilers will use return value optimization here.

### Use `\n` instead of `std::endl`

Avoid using `std::endl`, it is equivalent to `\n` but it will also flush the output, which can hurt performance. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n) for more details.